# Return one result from LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

if you have a select LINQ query that should only return one result, do you have to have a foreach loop to get the result?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myLinqObj = db.MyObjects.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 19):

```
// Will return a default value if no object is found in the DB
db.Table.SingleOrDefault(x => x.something == someParameter);
```

or

```
// Will throw an exception if records are not found
db.Table.Single(x => x.something == someParameter);
```

Thanks to Mehrdad for the comment...both lines have been updated.

If it's possible that your query could result in more than one record being returned, then (as mentioned in comments) `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` are the wrong methods to call. You would keep the same syntax, but call `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` respectively.

Comment: You can replace `.Where(predicate).Single()` with `.Single(predicate)`.

Comment: Single() will raise an exception if more than a single item exists in the sequence. If you don't care to throw an exception, you could also use First() or FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @Mehrdad - I made the change, but is there any performance difference between the two? I usually prefer .Where(predicate).Single() because I think it expresses my intent a little clearer.

Comment: @Justin: I doubt there's a noticeable performance difference. The expression tree will be slightly more verbose but the resulting SQL should be similar. `SingleOrDefault` has a similar overload too. I prefer these since they are more concise. By the way, `Single` will return the element if it contains **exactly one** element and throws an exception otherwise.

Comment: @Justin: You could have a very very minor difference as with the two-method chain you create one extra enumerator object. However, since object creation is pretty fast these days, you'll probably never notice it.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Since the OP said the query should return only one result, I used `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()`. If he would've said the query returned multiple results and he only needed the first, I would've suggested `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`. As for the style, you're probably right. I'm just living back in the SQL-like days.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either `First` or `Single`.

`First` returns the first row, whether there are multiple rows or just the one.

`Single` expects only one row to be returned, and throws an exception if there are multiple rows.

`Single` is therefore potentially a better choice if you expect to only have one row, so that you'll see the problem immediately and can troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use .First() or .FirstOrDefault() like so:

```
Foo foo = query.Select(a => a.Name == "foo").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If the query "**should** only return one result" Single is more effective as it throws if the query returns more than one, flagging bugs.

Answer (score 0):

From all the have have said my addition is the use the `Value` property after you have a single element if you are using LINQ-to-XML.

And the `Select new { *cols* }` if it a list or array or table.
Example.
... select new {c.Name, c.Value};

This tip is to enable you get the values.